# Warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am trying to build my first [COM Example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It?fid=866&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=26#_articleTop), I created a VS 2012 project. I got the errors in the library, which I solved by changing the `_WIN32_WINNT` to `0x0601` for Windows 7 and apparently changed `_WIN32_IE` to `0x0800` in `StdAfx.h`. Also I changed the `_WIN32_WINNT` in `Settings -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor` and now I am getting the errors as below

```
1>------ Build started: Project: COM, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  COMIntro.cpp
1>COMIntro.cpp(21): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated
1>COMIntro.cpp(21): warning C4100: 'envp' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>COMIntro.cpp(21): warning C4100: 'argv' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>COMIntro.cpp(21): warning C4100: 'argc' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>  StdAfx.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is it due to my windows SDK version which is 7.1 or some compatibility issue ?

Comment: Perhaps the project settings say to treat warnings as errors?

Answer (score -2):

I should have done some searching first. I got tangled up between COM and few other new concepts that I missed the conventional C++ dos and dont's

I just used cast. the unused variables were causing this problem

```
(void)argc;
(void)argv;
(void)envp;
```

Correct solution
Use of `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER` works for me.

Comment: Solution to what? To understanding compiler message "unreferenced formal parameter"?

Comment: Correct solution..Use of `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER` works for me @KonstantinL

Comment: Please elaborate the usage of the solution next time. If you are not gonna use a parameter, you can use the UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER macro to mark it as unused. Usage (write it within the function) :  UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(unused_variable);